# fullstack сайт и админ панель

Tags: reactjs, node.js, frontend, express, backend

Всем добрый день, столкнулся сегодня со следующей проблемой:
у меня в проекте есть три папки:

```
admin - админ панель (React)
backend - серверная часть сайта (Node.js + express)
frontend - основной сайт для клиента (React)
```

Хочу задать 2 вопроса:

1. Как реализовать переход на админ панель (на бэкенде сделать роут или на фронте)? к примеру может быть папку с админкой закинуть в фронтендер папку? или оставить как есть? что-то делать со структурой папок или оставить как есть?
2. Форму валидации при переходе на админ панель, полностью реализовывать всё в папке admin, или как-то сверстать в админке, а проверку на пароль и логин в панель уже писать на бэкенде?

Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Как по мне, админка должна быть физически отделена от клиентской части. Роут на бэке. Валидации делать все на бэке - с фронта логин/пароль, на бэке чекаем, ечли ок, отдаем данные

Comment: спасибо, так и сделаю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Спасибо пользователю SwaD!

Админ панель решили сделать отдельным проектом, роуты и авторизацию для админ панели реализовали через серверную часть!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: переделал, спасибо за поправку